# Logging behavior of rabbitmq docker container

Tags: docker, rabbitmq

I am using the `rabbitmq:3.10` image locally on my mac. By default rabbitmq emits info logs to console which can lead to a good amount of logging noise.

According to the [documentation](https://www.rabbitmq.com/configure.html#config-confd-directory) configuration changes such as logging changes can be adjusted via an additional `.conf` file in a separate folder that is declared via the RABBITMQ_CONFIG_FILES environment variable.

```
FROM  rabbitmq:3.10

ENV RABBITMQ_CONFIG_FILES=/local/my-conf.d/
COPY ./config/ /local/my-conf.d/
RUN chown -r rabbitmq:rabbitmq /local/my-conf.d/
```

In my local `conf` folder I have the file 'disable_logging.conf' with the [log level change](https://www.rabbitmq.com/logging.html#log-levels).

```
log.console.level = error
```

I build the image that way

```
docker build -t rabbitmqlocal .
```

and run it that way

```
docker run rabbitmqlocal
```

Whatever I do, I tried various `.conf` files, with or without `chown` rabbitmq always stops the boot process with `Application syslog exited with reason: stopped` in the logs

```
2022-09-26 12:41:03.377639+00:00 [notice] <0.44.0> Application syslog exited with reason: stopped
...
  Config file(s): /local/my-conf.d/disable_logging.conf
```

How do I change log level on a local rabbitmq docker container?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Please see a complete working example here:

https://github.com/lukebakken/stackoverflow-73854347

`Dockerfile` contents:

```
FROM  rabbitmq:3-management

RUN mkdir -p /etc/rabbitmq/conf.d
RUN chown -R rabbitmq:rabbitmq /etc/rabbitmq/conf.d
COPY 20-logging.conf /etc/rabbitmq/conf.d

EXPOSE 4369 5671 5672 15671 15672 15692 25672 35672-35682
```

`20-logging.conf` contents:

```
log.console = true
log.console.level = error
log.file.level = info
```

Answer (score 1):

Make sure to edit log-level in `rabbitmq.conf`
https://github.com/rabbitmq/rabbitmq-server/blob/main/deps/rabbit/docs/rabbitmq.conf.example

```
...
## Log level for file logging
##
 log.file.level = info
```

For Mac, this file is under `${install_prefix}/etc/rabbitmq/rabbitmq.conf`
please see: https://www.rabbitmq.com/configure.html#config-location

**Update**

But since Docker image is built on top of `ubuntu`:

```
Distributor ID: Ubuntu
Description:    Ubuntu 20.04.5 LTS
Release:    20.04
Codename:   focal
```

I connected within the container and started the server:

```bash
Starting broker...2022-09-27 08:23:22.933866+00:00 [info] <0.223.0>
2022-09-27 08:23:22.933866+00:00 [info] <0.223.0>  node           : rabbit@76814e18acec
2022-09-27 08:23:22.933866+00:00 [info] <0.223.0>  home dir       : /var/lib/rabbitmq
2022-09-27 08:23:22.933866+00:00 [info] <0.223.0>  config file(s) : /etc/rabbitmq/conf.d/10-defaults.conf
```

So it is reading configuration from `/etc/rabbitmq/conf.d/10-defaults.conf`

You should copy your configuration to path above, re-build again and it should update your log level

Comment: in  `/etc/rabbitmq/conf.d` there is a ' 10-defaults.conf' which sets `loopback_users.guest = false` and `log.console = true`. There is no `rabbitmq.conf` in the image.

Comment: you can remove this one and update your configurations in  `rabbitmq.conf` or keep this one and add your configurations

Comment: I have done that and it leads to the exact same outcome, I should have mentioned that, I tried to keep the question as clean as I could.