# How to reduce the amount of output text on Docker startup?

Tags: docker, docker-compose, rabbitmq

As part of my Docker Compose file, I start up rabbitmq as a service. What I'm encountering, is that the output text on startup is massive. This doesn't reduce any functionality - I'm just wondering if I can suppress the amount of information that rabbitmq shows on startup

Part of my docker-compose:

```yaml
message-broker:
    container_name: mq
    image: rabbitmq:3.10-management-alpine
    ports:
      - 15674:15672
      - 5674:5672
    restart: 
      on-failure
```

For example, here is the output on startup in Docker:

```
local-winions-message-broker | 2024-02-13 21:58:30.712678+00:00 [info] <0.223.0> Feature flags: list of feature flags found:
local-winions-message-broker | 2024-02-13 21:58:30.735312+00:00 [info] <0.223.0> Feature flags:   [ ] classic_mirrored_queue_version
local-winions-message-broker | 2024-02-13 21:58:30.736035+00:00 [info] <0.223.0> Feature flags:   [ ] classic_queue_type_delivery_support
local-winions-message-broker | 2024-02-13 21:58:30.736302+00:00 [info] <0.223.0> Feature flags:   [ ] implicit_default_bindings
local-winions-message-broker | 2024-02-13 21:58:30.736405+00:00 [info] <0.223.0> Feature flags:   [ ] maintenance_mode_status
local-winions-message-broker | 2024-02-13 21:58:30.736481+00:00 [info] <0.223.0> Feature flags:   [ ] quorum_queue
local-winions-message-broker | 2024-02-13 21:58:30.736549+00:00 [info] <0.223.0> Feature flags:   [ ] stream_queue
local-winions-message-broker | 2024-02-13 21:58:30.736658+00:00 [info] <0.223.0> Feature flags:   [ ] user_limits
local-winions-message-broker | 2024-02-13 21:58:30.736785+00:00 [info] <0.223.0> Feature flags:   [ ] virtual_host_metadata
local-winions-message-broker | 2024-02-13 21:58:30.736906+00:00 [info] <0.223.0> Feature flags: feature flag states written to disk: yes
local-winions-message-broker | 2024-02-13 21:58:31.465629+00:00 [notice] <0.44.0> Application syslog exited with reason: stopped
local-winions-message-broker | 2024-02-13 21:58:31.465802+00:00 [notice] <0.223.0> Logging: switching to configured handler(s); following messages may not be visible in this log output
local-winions-message-broker | 2024-02-13 21:58:31.489883+00:00 [notice] <0.223.0> Logging: configured log handlers are now ACTIVE
local-winions-message-broker | 2024-02-13 21:58:31.796149+00:00 [info] <0.223.0> ra: starting system quorum_queues
local-winions-message-broker | 2024-02-13 21:58:31.796269+00:00 [info] <0.223.0> starting Ra system: quorum_queues in directory: /var/lib/rabbitmq/mnesia/rabbit@ac91ae4746ff/quorum/rabbit@ac91ae4746ff
local-winions-message-broker | 2024-02-13 21:58:31.937261+00:00 [info] <0.259.0> ra system 'quorum_queues' running pre init for 0 registered servers
local-winions-message-broker | 2024-02-13 21:58:31.953113+00:00 [info] <0.260.0> ra: meta data store initialised for system quorum_queues. 0 record(s) recovered
local-winions-message-broker | 2024-02-13 21:58:31.978404+00:00 [notice] <0.265.0> WAL: ra_log_wal init, open tbls: ra_log_open_mem_tables, closed tbls: ra_log_closed_mem_tables
local-winions-message-broker | 2024-02-13 21:58:31.999491+00:00 [info] <0.223.0> ra: starting system coordination
local-winions-message-broker | 2024-02-13 21:58:31.999574+00:00 [info] <0.223.0> starting Ra system: coordination in directory: /var/lib/rabbitmq/mnesia/rabbit@ac91ae4746ff/coordination/rabbit@ac91ae4746ff
local-winions-message-broker | 2024-02-13 21:58:32.001505+00:00 [info] <0.272.0> ra system 'coordination' running pre init for 0 registered servers
local-winions-message-broker | 2024-02-13 21:58:32.002637+00:00 [info] <0.273.0> ra: meta data store initialised for system coordination. 0 record(s) recovered
local-winions-message-broker | 2024-02-13 21:58:32.002972+00:00 [notice] <0.278.0> WAL: ra_coordination_log_wal init, open tbls: ra_coordination_log_open_mem_tables, closed tbls: ra_coordination_log_closed_mem_tables
local-winions-message-broker | 2024-02-13 21:58:32.006453+00:00 [info] <0.223.0> 
local-winions-message-broker | 2024-02-13 21:58:32.006453+00:00 [info] <0.223.0>  Starting RabbitMQ 3.10.25 on Erlang 25.3.2.8 [jit]
local-winions-message-broker | 2024-02-13 21:58:32.006453+00:00 [info] <0.223.0>  Copyright (c) 2007-2023 VMware, Inc. or its affiliates.
local-winions-message-broker | 2024-02-13 21:58:32.006453+00:00 [info] <0.223.0>  Licensed under the MPL 2.0. Website: https://rabbitmq.com
local-winions-message-broker | 2024-02-13 21:58:32.006547+00:00 [error] <0.223.0> This release series has reached end of life and is no longer supported. Please visit https://rabbitmq.com/versions.html to learn more and upgrade
local-winions-message-broker | 
local-winions-message-broker |   ##  ##      RabbitMQ 3.10.25
local-winions-message-broker |   ##  ##
local-winions-message-broker |   ##########  Copyright (c) 2007-2023 VMware, Inc. or its affiliates.
local-winions-message-broker |   ######  ##
local-winions-message-broker |   ##########  Licensed under the MPL 2.0. Website: https://rabbitmq.com
local-winions-message-broker | 
local-winions-message-broker |   Erlang:      25.3.2.8 [jit]
local-winions-message-broker |   TLS Library: OpenSSL - OpenSSL 3.1.5 30 Jan 2024
local-winions-message-broker |   Release series support status: out of support
local-winions-message-broker | 
local-winions-message-broker |   Doc guides:  https://rabbitmq.com/documentation.html
local-winions-message-broker |   Support:     https://rabbitmq.com/contact.html
local-winions-message-broker |   Tutorials:   https://rabbitmq.com/getstarted.html
local-winions-message-broker |   Monitoring:  https://rabbitmq.com/monitoring.html
local-winions-message-broker | 
local-winions-message-broker |   Logs: /var/log/rabbitmq/rabbit@ac91ae4746ff_upgrade.log
local-winions-message-broker |         <stdout>
local-winions-message-broker | 
local-winions-message-broker |   Config file(s): /etc/rabbitmq/conf.d/10-defaults.conf
local-winions-message-broker | 
local-winions-message-broker |   Starting broker...2024-02-13 21:58:32.008184+00:00 [info] <0.223.0> 
local-winions-message-broker | 2024-02-13 21:58:32.008184+00:00 [info] <0.223.0>  node           : rabbit@ac91ae4746ff
local-winions-message-broker | 2024-02-13 21:58:32.008184+00:00 [info] <0.223.0>  home dir       : /var/lib/rabbitmq
local-winions-message-broker | 2024-02-13 21:58:32.008184+00:00 [info] <0.223.0>  config file(s) : /etc/rabbitmq/conf.d/10-defaults.conf
local-winions-message-broker | 2024-02-13 21:58:32.008184+00:00 [info] <0.223.0>  cookie hash    : g1m7reLoVZHZlQ07QnrMrg==
list of feature flags found:
local-winions-message-broker | 2024-02-13 21:58:37.571695+00:00 [info] <0.223.0> Feature flags:   [~] classic_mirrored_queue_version
local-winions-message-broker | 2024-02-13 21:58:37.571765+00:00 [info] <0.223.0> Feature flags:   [ ] classic_queue_type_delivery_support
local-winions-message-broker | 2024-02-13 21:58:37.571802+00:00 [info] <0.223.0> Feature flags:   [ ] drop_unroutable_metric
local-winions-message-broker | 2024-02-13 21:58:37.571842+00:00 [info] <0.223.0> Feature flags:   [ ] empty_basic_get_metric
local-winions-message-broker | 2024-02-13 21:58:37.571876+00:00 [info] <0.223.0> Feature flags:   [ ] implicit_default_bindings
local-winions-message-broker | 2024-02-13 21:58:37.571940+00:00 [info] <0.223.0> Feature flags:   [ ] maintenance_mode_status
local-winions-message-broker | 2024-02-13 21:58:37.571977+00:00 [info] <0.223.0> Feature flags:   [ ] quorum_queue
local-winions-message-broker | 2024-02-13 21:58:37.572006+00:00 [info] <0.223.0> Feature flags:   [ ] stream_queue
local-winions-message-broker | 2024-02-13 21:58:37.572035+00:00 [info] <0.223.0> Feature flags:   [ ] user_limits
local-winions-message-broker | 2024-02-13 21:58:37.572058+00:00 [info] <0.223.0> Feature flags:   [ ] virtual_host_metadata
local-winions-message-broker | 2024-02-13 21:58:37.572084+00:00 [info] <0.223.0> Feature flags: feature flag states written to disk: yes
local-winions-message-broker | 2024-02-13 21:58:37.585968+00:00 [info] <0.223.0> Feature flag `classic_mirrored_queue_version`: mark as enabled=true
local-winions-message-broker | 2024-02-13 21:58:37.588065+00:00 [info] <0.223.0> Feature flags: list of feature flags found:
local-winions-message-broker | 2024-02-13 21:58:37.588154+00:00 [info] <0.223.0> Feature flags:   [x] classic_mirrored_queue_version
local-winions-message-broker | 2024-02-13 21:58:37.588272+00:00 [info] <0.223.0> Feature flags:   [ ] classic_queue_type_delivery_support
local-winions-message-broker | 2024-02-13 21:58:37.588361+00:00 [info] <0.223.0> Feature flags:   [ ] drop_unroutable_metric
local-winions-message-broker | 2024-02-13 21:58:37.588522+00:00 [info] <0.223.0> Feature flags:   [ ] empty_basic_get_metric
local-winions-message-broker | 2024-02-13 21:58:37.588605+00:00 [info] <0.223.0> Feature flags:   [ ] implicit_default_bindings
local-winions-message-broker | 2024-02-13 21:58:37.588662+00:00 [info] <0.223.0> Feature flags:   [ ] maintenance_mode_status
local-winions-message-broker | 2024-02-13 21:58:37.588704+00:00 [info] <0.223.0> Feature flags:   [ ] quorum_queue
local-winions-message-broker | 2024-02-13 21:58:37.588815+00:00 [info] <0.223.0> Feature flags:   [ ] stream_queue
local-winions-message-broker | 2024-02-13 21:58:37.588856+00:00 [info] <0.223.0> Feature flags:   [ ] user_limits
local-winions-message-broker | 2024-02-13 21:58:37.588895+00:00 [info] <0.223.0> Feature flags:   [ ] virtual_host_metadata
local-winions-message-broker | 2024-02-13 21:58:37.588931+00:00 [info] <0.223.0> Feature flags: feature flag states written to disk: yes
local-winions-message-broker | 2024-02-13 21:58:37.601832+00:00 [info] <0.223.0> Feature flag `classic_queue_type_delivery_support`: supported, attempt to enable...
local-winions-message-broker | 2024-02-13 21:58:37.601990+00:00 [info] <0.223.0> Feature flag `classic_queue_type_delivery_support`: mark as enabled=state_changing
local-winions-message-broker | 2024-02-13 21:58:37.603427+00:00 [info] <0.223.0> Feature flags:
local-winions-message-broker | 2024-02-13 21:58:38.076040+00:00 [info] <0.223.0> Running boot step rabbit_exchange_type_headers defined by app rabbit
local-winions-message-broker | 2024-02-13 21:58:38.076172+00:00 [info] <0.223.0> Running boot step rabbit_exchange_type_topic defined by app rabbit
local-winions-message-broker | 2024-02-13 21:58:38.076274+00:00 [info] <0.223.0> Running boot step rabbit_mirror_queue_mode_all defined by app rabbit
local-winions-message-broker | 2024-02-13 21:58:38.076340+00:00 [info] <0.223.0> Running boot step rabbit_mirror_queue_mode_exactly defined by app rabbit
local-winions-message-broker | 2024-02-13 21:58:38.076492+00:00 [info] <0.223.0> Running boot step rabbit_mirror_queue_mode_nodes defined by app rabbit
local-winions-message-broker | 2024-02-13 21:58:38.077615+00:00 [info] <0.223.0> Running boot step rabbit_priority_queue defined by app rabbit
local-winions-message-broker | 2024-02-13 21:58:38.078131+00:00 [info] <0.223.0> Priority queues enabled, real BQ is rabbit_variable_queue
local-winions-message-broker | 2024-02-13 21:58:38.079254+00:00 [info] <0.223.0> Running boot step rabbit_queue_location_client_local defined by app rabbit
local-winions-message-broker | 2024-02-13 21:58:38.079739+00:00 [info] <0.223.0> Running boot step rabbit_queue_location_min_masters defined by app rabbit
local-winions-message-broker | 2024-02-13 21:58:38.079859+00:00 [info] <0.223.0> Running boot step rabbit_queue_location_random defined by app rabbit
local-winions-message-broker | 2024-02-13 21:58:38.080194+00:00 [info] <0.223.0> Running boot step kernel_ready defined by app rabbit
local-winions-message-broker | 2024-02-13 21:58:38.080322+00:00 [info] <0.223.0> Running boot step rabbit_sysmon_minder defined by app rabbit
local-winions-message-broker | 2024-02-13 21:58:38.080976+00:00 [info] <0.223.0> Running boot step rabbit_epmd_monitor defined by app rabbit
local-winions-message-broker | 2024-02-13 21:58:38.082389+00:00 [info] <0.564.0> epmd monitor knows us, inter-node communication (distribution) port: 25672
local-winions-message-broker | 2024-02-13 21:58:38.082528+00:00 [info] <0.223.0> Running boot step guid_generator defined by app rabbit
local-winions-message-broker | 2024-02-13 21:58:38.086195+00:00 [info] <0.223.0> Running boot step rabbit_node_monitor defined by app rabbit
local-winions-message-broker | 2024-02-13 21:58:38.086975+00:00 [info] <0.568.0> Starting rabbit_node_monitor
local-winions-message-broker | 2024-02-13 21:58:38.088759+00:00 [info] <0.223.0> Running boot step delegate_sup defined by app rabbit
local-winions-message-broker | 2024-02-13 21:58:38.090477+00:00 [info] <0.223.0> Running boot step rabbit_memory_monitor defined by app rabbit
local-winions-message-broker | 2024-02-13 21:58:38.091085+00:00 [info] <0.223.0> Running boot step rabbit_fifo_dlx_sup defined by app rabbit
local-winions-message-broker | 2024-02-13 21:58:38.091294+00:00 [info] <0.223.0> Running boot step core_initialized defined by app rabbit
local-winions-message-broker | 2024-02-13 21:58:38.091572+00:00 [info] <0.223.0> Running boot step upgrade_queues defined by app rabbit
local-winions-message-broker | 2024-02-13 21:58:38.104420+00:00 [info] <0.223.0> message_store upgrades: 1 to apply
local-winions-message-broker | 2024-02-13 21:58:38.104612+00:00 [info] <0.223.0> message_store upgrades: Applying rabbit_variable_queue:move_messages_to_vhost_store
local-winions-message-broker | 2024-02-13 21:58:38.105088+00:00 [info] <0.223.0> message_store upgrades: No durable queues found. Skipping message store migration
local-winions-message-broker | 2024-02-13 21:58:38.105152+00:00 [info] <0.223.0> message_store upgrades: Removing the old message store data
local-winions-message-broker | 2024-02-13 21:58:38.105868+00:00 [info] <0.223.0> message_store upgrades: All upgrades applied successfully
local-winions-message-broker | 2024-02-13 21:58:38.121456+00:00 [info] <0.223.0> Running boot step channel_tracking defined by app rabbit
local-winions-message-broker | 2024-02-13 21:58:38.125587+00:00 [info] <0.223.0> Setting up a table for channel tracking on this node: tracked_channel_on_node_rabbit@ac91ae4746ff
local-winions-message-broker | 2024-02-13 21:58:38.130077+00:00 [info] <0.223.0> Setting up a table for channel tracking on this node: tracked_channel_table_per_user_on_node_rabbit@ac91ae4746ff
local-winions-message-broker | 2024-02-13 21:58:38.131000+00:00 [info] <0.223.0> Running boot step rabbit_channel_tracking_handler defined by app rabbit
local-winions-message-broker | 2024-02-13 21:58:38.131150+00:00 [info] <0.223.0> Running boot step connection_tracking defined by app rabbit
local-winions-message-broker | 2024-02-13 21:58:38.135346+00:00 [info] <0.223.0> Setting up a table for connection tracking on this node: tracked_connection_on_node_rabbit@ac91ae4746ff
local-winions-message-broker | 2024-02-13 21:58:38.139560+00:00 [info] <0.223.0> Setting up a table for per-vhost connection counting on this node: tracked_connection_per_vhost_on_node_rabbit@ac91ae4746ff
local-winions-message-broker | 2024-02-13 21:58:38.143898+00:00 [info] <0.223.0> Setting up a table for per-user connection counting on this node: tracked_connection_table_per_user_on_node_rabbit@ac91ae4746ff
local-winions-message-broker | 2024-02-13 21:58:38.144509+00:00 [info] <0.223.0> Running boot step rabbit_connection_tracking_handler defined by app rabbit
local-winions-message-broker | 2024-02-13 21:58:38.145614+00:00 [info] <0.223.0> Running boot step rabbit_definitions_hashing defined by app rabbit
local-winions-message-broker | 2024-02-13 21:58:38.145774+00:00 [info] <0.223.0> Running boot step rabbit_exchange_parameters defined by app rabbit
local-winions-message-broker | 2024-02-13 21:58:38.146721+00:00 [info] <0.223.0> Running boot step rabbit_mirror_queue_misc defined by app rabbit
local-winions-message-broker | 2024-02-13 21:58:38.146957+00:00 [info] <0.223.0> Running boot step rabbit_policies defined by app rabbit
local-winions-message-broker | 2024-02-13 21:58:38.148194+00:00 [info] <0.223.0> Running boot step rabbit_policy defined by app rabbit
local-winions-message-broker | 2024-02-13 21:58:38.148292+00:00 [info] <0.223.0> Running boot step rabbit_queue_location_validator defined by app rabbit
local-winions-message-broker | 2024-02-13 21:58:38.148340+00:00 [info] <0.223.0> Running boot step rabbit_quorum_memory_manager defined by app rabbit
local-winions-message-broker | 2024-02-13 21:58:38.148436+00:00 [info] <0.223.0> Running boot step rabbit_stream_coordinator defined by app rabbit
local-winions-message-broker | 2024-02-13 21:58:38.148579+00:00 [info] <0.223.0> Running boot step rabbit_vhost_limit defined by app rabbit
local-winions-message-broker | 2024-02-13 21:58:38.148640+00:00 [info] <0.223.0> Running boot step rabbit_mgmt_reset_handler defined by app rabbitmq_management
local-winions-message-broker | 2024-02-13 21:58:38.148698+00:00 [info] <0.223.0> Running boot step rabbit_mgmt_db_handler defined by app rabbitmq_management_agent
local-winions-message-broker | 2024-02-13 21:58:38.148732+00:00 [info] <0.223.0> Management plugin: using rates mode 'basic'
local-winions-message-broker | 2024-02-13 21:58:38.150389+00:00 [info] <0.223.0> Running boot step recovery defined by app rabbit
local-winions-message-broker | 2024-02-13 21:58:38.151726+00:00 [info] <0.223.0> Running boot step empty_db_check defined by app rabbit
local-winions-message-broker | 2024-02-13 21:58:38.151810+00:00 [info] <0.223.0> Will seed default virtual host and user...
local-winions-message-broker | 2024-02-13 21:58:38.151993+00:00 [info] <0.223.0> Adding vhost '/' (description: 'Default virtual host', tags: [])
local-winions-message-broker | 2024-02-13 21:58:38.168686+00:00 [info] <0.630.0> Making sure data directory '/var/lib/rabbitmq/mnesia/rabbit@ac91ae4746ff/msg_stores/vhosts/628WB79CIFDYO9LJI6DKMI09L' for vhost '/' exists
local-winions-message-broker | 2024-02-13 21:58:38.170711+00:00 [info] <0.630.0> Setting segment_entry_count for vhost '/' with 0 queues to '2048'
local-winions-message-broker | 2024-02-13 21:58:38.175489+00:00 [info] <0.630.0> Starting message stores for vhost '/'
local-winions-message-broker | 2024-02-13 21:58:38.175940+00:00 [info] <0.635.0> Message store "628WB79CIFDYO9LJI6DKMI09L/msg_store_transient": using rabbit_msg_store_ets_index to provide index
local-winions-message-broker | 2024-02-13 21:58:38.177884+00:00 [info] <0.630.0> Started message store of type transient for vhost '/'
local-winions-message-broker | 2024-02-13 21:58:38.178232+00:00 [info] <0.639.0> Message store "628WB79CIFDYO9LJI6DKMI09L/msg_store_persistent": using rabbit_msg_store_ets_index to provide index
local-winions-message-broker | 2024-02-13 21:58:38.178907+00:00 [warning] <0.639.0> Message store "628WB79CIFDYO9LJI6DKMI09L/msg_store_persistent": rebuilding indices from scratch
local-winions-message-broker | 2024-02-13 21:58:38.179866+00:00 [info] <0.630.0> Started message store of type persistent for vhost '/'
local-winions-message-broker | 2024-02-13 21:58:38.180163+00:00 [info] <0.630.0> Recovering 0 queues of type rabbit_classic_queue took 8ms
local-winions-message-broker | 2024-02-13 21:58:38.180221+00:00 [info] <0.630.0> Recovering 0 queues of type rabbit_quorum_queue took 0ms
local-winions-message-broker | 2024-02-13 21:58:38.180312+00:00 [info] <0.630.0> Recovering 0 queues of type rabbit_stream_queue took 0ms
local-winions-message-broker | 2024-02-13 21:58:38.184813+00:00 [info] <0.223.0> Created user 'guest'
local-winions-message-broker | 2024-02-13 21:58:38.187020+00:00 [info] <0.223.0> Successfully set user tags for user 'guest' to [administrator]
local-winions-message-broker | 2024-02-13 21:58:38.189236+00:00 [info] <0.223.0> Successfully set permissions for 'guest' in virtual host '/' to '.*', '.*', '.*'
local-winions-message-broker | 2024-02-13 21:58:38.189316+00:00 [info] <0.223.0> Running boot step rabbit_observer_cli defined by app rabbit
local-winions-message-broker | 2024-02-13 21:58:38.189675+00:00 [info] <0.223.0> Running boot step rabbit_looking_glass defined by app rabbit
local-winions-message-broker | 2024-02-13 21:58:38.189738+00:00 [info] <0.223.0> Running boot step rabbit_core_metrics_gc defined by app rabbit
local-winions-message-broker | 2024-02-13 21:58:38.190273+00:00 [info] <0.223.0> Running boot step background_gc defined by app rabbit
local-winions-message-broker | 2024-02-13 21:58:38.190598+00:00 [info] <0.223.0> Running boot step routing_ready defined by app rabbit
local-winions-message-broker | 2024-02-13 21:58:38.190651+00:00 [info] <0.223.0> Running boot step pre_flight defined by app rabbit
local-winions-message-broker | 2024-02-13 21:58:38.190818+00:00 [info] <0.223.0> Running boot step notify_cluster defined by app rabbit
local-winions-message-broker | 2024-02-13 21:58:38.191362+00:00 [info] <0.223.0> Running boot step networking defined by app rabbit
local-winions-message-broker | 2024-02-13 21:58:38.191425+00:00 [info] <0.223.0> Running boot step definition_import_worker_pool defined by app rabbit
local-winions-message-broker | 2024-02-13 21:58:38.191505+00:00 [info] <0.280.0> Starting worker pool 'definition_import_pool' with 2 processes in it
local-winions-message-broker | 2024-02-13 21:58:38.192077+00:00 [info] <0.223.0> Running boot step cluster_name defined by app rabbit
local-winions-message-broker | 2024-02-13 21:58:38.192188+00:00 [info] <0.223.0> Initialising internal cluster ID to 'rabbitmq-cluster-id-2W1ganXUoZBIZlf6OaPisA'
local-winions-message-broker | 2024-02-13 21:58:38.194454+00:00 [info] <0.223.0> Running boot step direct_client defined by app rabbit
local-winions-message-broker | 2024-02-13 21:58:38.195182+00:00 [info] <0.223.0> Running boot step rabbit_maintenance_mode_state defined by app rabbit
local-winions-message-broker | 2024-02-13 21:58:38.195464+00:00 [info] <0.223.0> Creating table rabbit_node_maintenance_states for feature flag `maintenance_mode_status`
local-winions-message-broker | 2024-02-13 21:58:38.197746+00:00 [info] <0.223.0> Running boot step rabbit_management_load_definitions defined by app rabbitmq_management
local-winions-message-broker | 2024-02-13 21:58:38.197943+00:00 [info] <0.671.0> Resetting node maintenance status
local-winions-message-broker | 2024-02-13 21:58:38.219613+00:00 [info] <0.736.0> Management plugin: HTTP (non-TLS) listener started on port 15672
local-winions-message-broker | 2024-02-13 21:58:38.219825+00:00 [info] <0.764.0> Statistics database started.
local-winions-message-broker | 2024-02-13 21:58:38.219908+00:00 [info] <0.763.0> Starting worker pool 'management_worker_pool' with 3 processes in it
local-winions-message-broker | 2024-02-13 21:58:38.235314+00:00 [info] <0.778.0> Prometheus metrics: HTTP (non-TLS) listener started on port 15692
local-winions-message-broker | 2024-02-13 21:58:38.235539+00:00 [info] <0.671.0> Ready to start client connection listeners
local-winions-message-broker | 2024-02-13 21:58:38.238342+00:00 [info] <0.822.0> started TCP listener on [::]:5672
local-winions-message-broker |  completed with 4 plugins.
local-winions-message-broker | 2024-02-13 21:58:38.352026+00:00 [info] <0.671.0> Server startup complete; 4 plugins started.
local-winions-message-broker | 2024-02-13 21:58:38.352026+00:00 [info] <0.671.0>  * rabbitmq_prometheus
local-winions-message-broker | 2024-02-13 21:58:38.352026+00:00 [info] <0.671.0>  * rabbitmq_management
local-winions-message-broker | 2024-02-13 21:58:38.352026+00:00 [info] <0.671.0>  * rabbitmq_web_dispatch
local-winions-message-broker | 2024-02-13 21:58:38.352026+00:00 [info] <0.671.0>  * rabbitmq_management_agent
```

There is literally so many characters that Stack Overflow limits me to 30,000. The whole output is ~50K chars.

Comment: How do you start Docker Compose? If you use the `-d` detach option, you won't have to look at the logs (unless you want to see them with the `docker-compose logs` command).

Comment: You could also look at suppressing info/notice messages in RabbitMQ - that would be in the docs.

Comment: Aha, this is a better duplicate: [Logging behavior of rabbitmq docker container](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73854347/logging-behavior-of-rabbitmq-docker-container)

Comment: that seems to be what I'm looking for, thanks!